# ExecuteScalar won't work even though Connection is open in ASP.net

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am trying to use the `ExecuteScalar` function to get a certain data from my database but an error prompts that `ExecuteScalar` requires an open and available Connection even though I have explicitly opened it. `ExecuteScalar` function works on the other parts of my program except on this one (which this code is located on an else part of a nested-ifs. The code is as follows:

```
else if (drpAccType.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Nurse")
{
    Connection.Open();
    SqlCommand getlatestID = new SqlCommand("select ID from tblListofMedicine accountType = 'Nurse' order by ID desc", Connection.conn);


    int userIDD = Convert.ToInt32(getID.ExecuteScalar());
    num = num * (userIDD + 1);
    string IDtoAdd = Convert.ToString(num).Substring(2, 4);

    addID = "N" + IDtoAdd;

}
```

This code is inside a nested-ifs and I have come to realize that every time I do an `ExecuteScalar` function inside an else function, it won't work but outside an else, it works.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: What's `getID` ? Where is it being created and configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified `getID` instead of `getlatestID`

```
int userIDD = Convert.ToInt32(getlatestID.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: This answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: Done! I apologize for the careless question though. Thanks a lot!